# Which locale is set by default on US browsers

Tags: internationalization

I'm writing an application which builds some PDF documents, and I have to support both American an European users.

So I would like to provide documents in "Letter" size for US and Canadian users, and A4 for the rest of the world.

I was thinking to use the browser locale for that. But I don't know how browsers are usually configured in US. Do they mostly use the "en" locale or "en-US" ?

BTW, is there an another way to detect the users' preference about paper size... ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any browser statistic that would give even a rough tendency to that question.
(BTW: having such data does not mean that you actual visitors will fit into that scheme)
You can try to find a combined heuristic to increase your bets e.g. using:

- Browser locale
- some IP to location service (e.g. http://www.ip2location.com/)
- even requesting the location via browser api is a possible way - though people have to agree explicitly to send you that data [GEO-location HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: I'm more interested in the default configurations of US computers, . e.g. when you install Windows or get a brand new Apple computer, which locale do you get? What about on Android / other mobile OS?